# <jdoc:include type="component" /> displaying home

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am building my first joomla site I am stuck here- when I am including at my templates index.php.

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

It is displaying Home at my front end. Can't find the solution need help.

Comment: That's exactly what that is supposed to do.

Comment: @user2742008 - You do realise the answer below involves editing a core file within the template which is not recommended. What is being displayed is most likely the article name. This can be disabled in the article parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Custom Html module frontcomp and display it only on home page without writing any thing in it.
then add the following in index.php(template)

```
<?php if($this->countModules('frontcomp')) : ?>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="frontcomp" style="xhtml" />
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(!$this->countModules('frontcomp')) : ?>
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
<?php endif; ?>
```